# jQuery loading content when div clicked - content jumping

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery that is displaying content when a div is clicked...

```
<ul>
    <li class="tab"><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content1">Link 1</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content2">Link 2</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content3">Link 3</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content4">Link 4</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content5">Link 5</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="content-container">
    <div id="content1">This is the test content for part 1</div>
    <div id="content2">This is the test content for part 2</div>
    <div id="content3">This is the test content for part 3</div>
    <div id="content4">This is the test content for part 4</div>
    <div id="content5">This is the test content for part 5</div>
</div>


<!-- language: lang-js -->

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(function () {
        jQuery(".link").click(function () {
            if (jQuery(this).hasClass('active')) {
                return;
            }

            jQuery('.active').removeClass('active');
            jQuery(this.parentNode).addClass('active');

            jQuery('.content-container div').fadeOut('slow');
            jQuery('#' + jQuery(this).data('rel')).fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zd2ykjoy/

It is working great, however, I want to set it so that when the page loads, the first tab is automatically selected.

Also,  when there is content above, clicking on any of the tabs makes the page jump to the bottom of the content, any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Btw: `jQuery(function() {})` is a shorthand version of `jQuery(document).ready(function() {})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `jQuery(".link").first().click();` to select the first tab when the page is started.

If you don't return `false` from you click event handler function, then clicking a link will scroll (to the top of the page, not the bottom!). If you make it return false, then it will not scroll at all.

See the edited JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zd2ykjoy/1/

Comment: Thanks, thats solved that one.  Still can't work out why the page is jumping when a tab is clicked though

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, makes total sense now

Answer (score 1):

To load first tab when page loads try this:

```
jQuery(".link")[0].click();
```

and to avoid page jumping when clicking links, try this:

```
jQuery(".link").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
```